# Ember 2.4 + EmberFire findAll sorting descending

Tags: ember.js, firebase, emberfire

App: Ember 2.4
DB: FireBase;

Can't get data sorted with descending direction.

Using

```
    export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.query('message', {
            orderBy : 'time'
        });
    }
});
```

for getting list of my messages. But I need to get it in descending direction.

Have already read EmberFire doc and api doc
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ember/guide.html
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ember/api.html

I didn't find any clear explanation in Ember 2.4 guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, Firebase doesn't have this support out of the box, however you can convert your model array to Array and reverse the list.

You can do this conversion anywhere, for example in `afterModel()`:

```
afterModel(model) {
  return model.toArray().reverse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: To select last 5 messages from collection ordered by time.

```
model: function() {
         this.store.query('message', {
             orderBy : 'time',
             limitToLast: 5
         }).then((arrModel)=>{
            return arrModel.toArray().reverse(); 
         });
     }
```